# query and get also information 2 backrefs deep

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a `many-many` table between user and auctions called `placedBids`.

I am querying from auction so I backref in `placedBids` called also `placedbids` so I can access it from auction, and then I can get for example the `userid` of the placed bids, but I really want its the `username`, so i created a backref in the relation between `user` and `placedbids` called `userbids` (this I changed because there is already another backref called `users`, though maybe there where some problem) to try to do it, I am new in `sqlalchemy` I have tried many things, even a eager loading in the `userbids` backref to no avail.

this is my last query:

```
auction = dbsession.query(Auction.id, Auction.endTime, Auction.currentPrice, Product.description, Product.title, User.username, PlacedBids.timeplaced, PlacedBids.userbids.username).outerjoin(Auction.placedbids).join(Auction.products).outerjoin(Auction.leader).filter( Auction.id == request.matchdict['id']).all()
```

error:

> 2012-05-18T16:40:36+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttri
>   bute' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'username'

I have tried also joining in like `outerjoin(Auction.placedbids.userbids)` or `PlacedBids.userbids` and so on...

I don't have much experience with `sqlalchemy`, I can make an extra query to get the `username` with the `user_id` I can get without problems, but I want to know how to make without that.

Answer (score 0):

joins must always be explicit, and specify the lead entity attributes in terms of their actual parent class.   There is no "multiple dotted" access between related classes - that implies joining which must always be separately tated.

Assuming here PlacedBids.userbids is an instance of UserBid:

```
auction = dbsession.query(Auction.id, Auction.endTime, 
   Auction.currentPrice, Product.description, Product.title, User.username, 
    PlacedBids.timeplaced, UserBid.username).\
    outerjoin(Auction.placedbids).\
    join(Auction.products).\
    outerjoin(Auction.leader).\
    outerjoin(PlaceBids.userbids).\ 
    filter( Auction.id == request.matchdict['id']).all()
```

Comment: userbids is a backref to User, and i already used User.username from the Auction.leader that its a relation to User and shows fine, so how do i access then the one in PlacedBids.userbids, maybe creating some kind of alias for that one? thanks

Comment: auction = dbsession.query(Auction.id, Auction.endTime, Auction.created, Auction.currentPrice, Product.description, Product.title, User.username, PlacedBids.timeplaced, PlacedBids.user_id, user_alias.username ).outerjoin(Auction.placedbids).join(Auction.products).outerjoin(Auction.leader).outerjoin(user_alias, PlacedBids.userbids).filter( Auction.id == request.matchdict['id']).all()           worked! thanks anyway, helped me exclude some ideas, btw great orm